# R : Get Exact Value of Zeroes (Kilos to 1000 and so on)

Tags: r

I have a datasets which like this:

```
dd <- read.csv(text="
value,zeroes 
1   ,1
12  ,2
123 ,k
1234,K
5   ,5
56  ,m
567 ,M")
```

I want to convert them to their exact number. The zeroes value indicate how many zeroes should be on the end of value. There are So the results should show up like this :

```
extracted
10
1200
123000
1234000
500000
56000000
567000000
```

There are 13 factor levels on zeroes value, how should I approach this in r? Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a look up vector to tell how much each value should be scaled by

```
scale <- 10^c("1"=1, "2"=2, k=3, K=4, "5"=5, m=6, M=7)
```

And then can use that to weight your numbers. You'll either want to make sure your column is a character column, or if it's a factor, make sure the factor levels are in the same order as the data.

```
format(
  transform(dd, expand = value * scale[as.character(zeroes)]),
scientific=20)
#   value zeroes     expand
# 1     1      1         10
# 2    12      2       1200
# K   123      k    1230000
# 5  1234      K  123400000
# k     5      5       5000
# m    56      m   56000000
# M   567      M 5670000000
```

The `format()` here is just to turn off the default scientific notation

For the factor method you would do

```
dd$zeros <- factor(d$zeros, levels=names(scale))
transform(dd, expand = value * scale[zeroes])
```

Comment: This works good, although i use them directly without transform and format. `dd$expand <- dd$value* scale[dd$zeroes]` which give scientific notation, but I'm okay with that

Comment: also, it seems more correct to have zeroes column as character `dd$zeroes <- as.character(dd$zeroes)` rather than as factor

Answer (score 1):

We can write a function :

```
return_zeroes <- function(x) {
   if(grepl('\\d', x)) 
      paste0(rep(0, x), collapse = "")
   else switch(tolower(x), 'm'='000000','k'= '000')
}
```

and use `sapply` to call it.

```
df$extracted <- as.numeric(paste0(df$value, sapply(df$zeroes, return_zeroes)))

df
#  value zeroes extracted
#1     1      1        10
#2    12      2      1200
#3   123      k    123000
#4  1234      K   1234000
#5     5      5    500000
#6    56      m  56000000
#7   567      M 567000000
```

You may add more expressions in `switch` statement if you have more abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

Following [MrFlick Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61400863/8283794), I'd like to provide the solution which got through my problem, and I'd like to compare it between zeroes as factor and character

The scale should be:

```
scale <- 10^c("1"=1, "2"=2, "k"=3, "K"=3, "5"=5, "m"=6, "M"=6)
```

compare between zeroes as factor and character

```
dd$zeroes <- as.factor(dd$zeroes)
format(
     transform(dd, expand = value * scale[zeroes]),
     scientific=20)
#
value zeroes    expand
     1      1        10
    12      2      1200
   123      k    123000
  1234      K 123400000
     5      5      5000
    56      m  56000000
   567      M 567000000

###############
dd$zeroes <- as.character(dd$zeroes)
format(
     transform(dd, expand = value * scale[zeroes]),
     scientific=20)
#
value zeroes    expand
     1      1        10
    12      2      1200
   123      k    123000
  1234      K   1234000
     5      5    500000
    56      m  56000000
   567      M 567000000
```

We can the difference results in zeroes values K and 5.
I'm not sure as to why it got different result between as factor and as character

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. If you have factors, you want to make sure that the factors are in the right order. The reason is that when you index with a factor it indexes numerical ls by level, but when you index by character, it matches on the names.